# convert javascript to python : looping for in python

Tags: javascript, python

I have the javascript code and i want to convert it to python.

```
var dice = [1, 3, 4, 1]

for(let i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
    if(dice[i] == 1 ) {
        dice.splice(i, 1)
        break;
    }
}
```

whats wrong?

```
q = [1, 2,3, 4]
for i, dice in q: 
    if dice[i] == 1:
        dice = splice(i, 1)
        break
print dice
```

I want if the number one appears simultaneously then the number 1 is discarded.

How the python code for the js code above?

Comment: As a start, you can try write correct python code from what you understand of javascript code...

Comment: just write a normal for loop with remove the desired index from list , which part did you get stuck?

Comment: like an above??

Comment: How does your python code  output differ from the desired output?

Comment: function splice not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
dice = [1, 3, 4, 1]
newval = ''
for i in range(len(dice)):
    if dice[i] == 1:
        newval = dice[1:i]
    print(newval)
```

Comment: Could someone please explain why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
q = [1, 2,3, 4]
for dice in q: 
    if dice == 1:
        q.remove(dice)
        break

print(q);
```

Comment: this work but function splice not work

Comment: I'm not sure if `splice` works that way in python. I'm also learning python. Can't comment on that :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer but you are removing each value from the list each time.  The JavaScript code above does not do this.  It splits the list.  This may cause problems if the list (in entirety) needs to be used later.